# How can I see all terraform variables?

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to see all variables a stack is spun up with? In my case, we have several workspaces with several variables set by another engineer.

I'm trying to work out if there's a way I can print them out as some are causing errors in `terraform plan`.

Comment: Please make sure you add more context. If terraform commands are complaining about missing values for variables, then that is the first place to look. Usually variables are defined in a dedicated file named `variables.tf` but we cannot know that in your case.

Answer (score 0):

`terraform show` gets you pretty far, and variables may be inferred from the stack contents

`variables.tf` shows you which variables are available, but obviously not which values were called when the stack was spun up